# Is there a time limit for recording audio on a PowerPoint slide?

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm recording audio files in a PowerPoint presentation (Slide Show / Record Slide Show). Some of the longer narrations truncate. Does anyone know if there is a time limit per slide?

If so, can it be increased?

Answer (score 0):

There's no *MS-documented* time limit, but in practice, users do find that some versions of PPT do truncate audio. As it happens, I've been looking into this a bit and have been collecting reports from users who run into the problem. So far 40 seconds seems to be the magic number.  Narration shorter than that doesn't seem to get cut off.  It appears to be more a bug in how PPT "reads" the length of the audio file than an actual limit, so there's no fix until MS comes up with one.  I suspect you could work around the problem by keeping your narrations down to say 35 or 30 seconds per slide; for slides that require longer narration, add a second duplicate slide to add the remainder of the narration to and then set the transition to the duplicate slide to automatic.

Comment: Still experience the truncation effect in PowerPoint 2013 (15.0.5257.1000) MSO (15.0.5259.1000) 64-bit. Cannot overcome a time limit of 38 sec. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried recording the narration independently of PPT (ie, in Audacity or similar), exporting each slide's worth of narration to MP3 and adding those files to PPT? The help file for my (for now, free) PPTools Narrator add-in has a lot of tips. Another: try different export settings when saving the MP3s from Audacity; some seem to trigger cut-offs, others don't.  The add-in is here: http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00004-PPTools-Narrator.htm

Comment: Thank you. Being depressed I developed a small workflow, where used standard Windows Sound Recorder: https://superuser.com/a/1568263

Comment: By the way, recording narration independently seems much better than using PowerPoint, because you can open the text and read it while recording. Then you import it to PowerPoint and record cursor and annotations.

Comment: That, and you can control the recording quality, or at least that's the case in Audacity. Which is also free, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

My workflow for the independent recording of narrations for Windows 7 and PowerPoint 2013 is the following (for a single slide).

1. Set your mic up at the **Recording** tab of the in the standard **Sound** application
2. Open the standard Windows **Sound Recorder**, record narration for Slide 01, and save it in WMA format with the name "Slide 01.wma" in the target folder.
3. Open the target slide in PowerPoint and drag the WMA file and drop it to the slide.
4. Select the grey speaker icon, move it in white space of the slide, go to **PLAYBACK** ribbon, tick **Hide During Show**, and use **Trim Audio** to crop the track as required, etc.
5. Go to **ANIMATIONS** ribbon, in **Timing** group: in **Reorder Animation** push **Move Earlier** (turns to grey), in **Start:** set **With Previous**. This makes the narration track start playing when the slide appears on the screen.
6. Go to **SLIDE SHOW** ribbon and call **Record Slide Show Start Recording from Current Slide**, then clear tick from **Slide and animation timings**.
7. The slide appears, and the narration track starts playing. Listen to the narration and, at the right time, use **Laser Pointer** (Ctrl + left mouse click) if needed. Once done, push the Escape button on the keyboard.
8. Notice that another (dummy) grey speaker icon appears at the bottom left of the slide. This is a dummy track (up to 5 sec) that PowerPoint recorded at the previous step. Select it and simply delete it (push the Del button on the keyboard).
9. Go to **SLIDE SHOW** ribbon and call **From Current Slide** at the **Start Slide Show** group to check that everything is well done.

I hope this would help you in making excellent recordings.

Answer (score 0):

I have PPT version 2111.  I not only find that it truncates my audio, but it truncates my entire presentation.  It won't let me record past slide 26 of a 60 slide deck.  The current file size is just under 32 GB.  And PPT suggests that what is recorded is just over 18 minutes.

To address the truncation, I added an invisible shape (an oval with both outline and fill set to none) and added it at the end of the animation with enough delay that it plays back my full slide narration.

I haven't overcome the appraent size limit on the overall recording.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1102933)