# PowerPoint 2013(6): set slide timings to narration durations

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint, gui, timing

I accidentally ran **Clear Timings on All Slides** command and lost all slide timings.
However, each slide of my presentation has narrations.
Is there a GUI/VBA way to set slide timings to narration durations for all the slides?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a temporary workaround:

1. Select the audio clip on the slide.
2. Under **Audio Tools**, on the **Playback** tab, click **Trim Audio**.
   Note total playback duration see the top right corner.
3. Manually adjust **Adjust** slide timing on the **Transitions** tab, in the **Timing** group, under **Advance Slide**, in **After** input box.

The workflow works but is manual and therefore laborious.

Do you know a way to read the total audio playback duration through VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of VBA that'll give you the total lengths of the sounds in your presentation (and along the way, returns the sound for each ... you can modify the code if you need to split that out):

```
Sub SumSoundLengths()

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim sngLengthOfSound As Single
    Dim sngSoundDuration As Single
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
            If oSh.MediaType = ppMediaTypeSound Then
                With oSh
                    sngLengthOfSound = .MediaFormat.Length
                    sngSoundDuration = sngSoundDuration + sngLengthOfSound
                End With
            End If
        End If
        Next
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Sounds total to: " & CStr(sngSoundDuration)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a script I came up with, based on Steve’s answer here. I ran into an issue with the slide transition variable exceeding a seemingly arbitrary limit of 86.4 for some reason. If you change that number, and it doesn’t give you an error, feel free to remove it all together.

```
Sub SetTransitionTimings()

      Dim shapeObj As Shape
      Dim slideObj As Slide
      Dim sngLengthOfSound As Single
      Dim slideDuration As Single

      For Each slideObj In ActivePresentation.Slides

              slideDuration = 0

              For Each shapeObj In slideObj.Shapes

                              If shapeObj.Type = msoMedia Then
                                             If shapeObj.MediaType = ppMediaTypeSound Then
                                                            With shapeObj
                                                                    .AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.PlayOnEntry = msoTrue
                                                                    sngLengthOfSound = .MediaFormat.Length / 1000
                                                                    slideDuration = slideDuration + sngLengthOfSound
                                                            End With
                                             End If
                              End If

              Next

              If slideDuration = 0 Then
                              slideDuration = 5
              End If

              If slideDuration < 86.4 Then
                            With slideObj.SlideShowTransition
                                    .AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
                                    .Duration = 1
                                    .AdvanceTime = slideDuration
                            End With
              Else
                            Debug.Print "Slide " & slideObj.SlideNumber & ": " & slideDuration
              End If

      Next

      MsgBox "Transition timings set."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that the latest version of PowerPoint appears to have a bug that causes havoc with timings. Apparently under the ribbon option TRANSITIONS, the option to "Advance Slide After XXX seconds" is automatically checked by default. If you edit any transitions and do NOT un-check this, all your timings are erased and replaced with the number shown in the ribbon option.

I have spent days trying to fix presentations that had their narration timings erased, going so far as to re-record narrations (no joy) and then resorting to screengrabbing myself running entire presentation manually and then converting to video. It was Jon G's solution above that fixed this, in all of about 25 seconds.

Thanks, Jon!